# VBA type mismatch in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-7, windows-xp, mismatch

Good afternoon all

I'm attmepting to implement an audit trail for a small database here at work and I've borrowed my code from Martin Greens' Fontstuff website
[Martin Green's Audit trail](http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut21.htm)

so I have a code module that constist of

```
Sub AuditChanges(IDField As String)
On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ctl As Control
Dim datTimeCheck As Date
Dim strUserID As String
Dim strReason As String
Dim strName As String

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
datTimeCheck = Now()
strUserID = Environ("USERNAME")

strReason = InputBox("Enter Reason", "Reason")
'strName = InputBox("Enter Name", "Name")

For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
    If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
        If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
            With rst
                .AddNew
                ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                ![UserName] = strUserID
                ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                ![Reason] = strReason
                ![Name] = CurrentUser()
                .Update
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next ctl

AuditChanges_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub

AuditChanges_Err:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub
```

and a short line in the before update method of each control on a form as follows

```
If Not Me.NewRecord Then Call AuditChanges("ID")
```

My problem being if I run the database on a windows 7 machine everything works as it should.

We do however have a few XP machines on which the dB has to be accessed and for some reason I get a type mismatch error when the code is executed unfortunately I'm unable to access these machines easily as they are on a different site

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: unfortunatley I don't have access to an XP machine they are on another site 60 miles away

Comment: done thanks for the pointer Hans

Comment: Could it be the ADO version?  Windows 7 where you're developing has access to later version than an XP machine would.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: How do you support those remote users?  Can you use remote login or any screen sharing method?  Do you have a tech support person at the remote site?  You need to get eyeballs on the problem details.

Comment: Thanks for your input Hans I've actually managed to find and old XP machine in this building and the code above works as it should on that. I've asked if the user can check that various libraries etc are the same as we have here I'll let you know the outcome

Comment: You can ask the remote user to run this as a single line in the Access Immediate window: `for i = 1 to references.count : ? references(i).Name, references(i).Major, references(i).Minor, references(i).IsBroken : next`

Comment: If nothing shows True for `IsBroken`, the library versions are not the cause of your problem.

Comment: looks like it may be the ADO version as Sobigen suggests I've managed to find and XP machine here and both that and windows 7 are using msado28.dll where as the machines at the other site look to be using msado1.5.dll, I'll ask if it can be changed back there

Comment: Hans just seen your comment I'll ask them to try that also

Comment: Thanks Hans it looks like that might be my problem I'll e-mail a colleague on the other site and ask him to give your immediate window suggestion a go

Comment: Problem solved many thanks changed ado library for a different one then changed back again all your help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is the consolidation of all the comments into answer.

Check the ADO version of the remote machines. Windows 7 where you're developing has access to later version than an XP machine would.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

---

From [HansUp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77335/hansup)
You can ask the remote user to run this as a single line in the Access Immediate window:

```
for i = 1 to references.count : ? references(i).Name, references(i).Major, references(i).Minor, references(i).IsBroken : next
```

If nothing shows True for IsBroken, the library versions are not the cause of your problem.